# In-App Purchase Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to add in-app purchase to my app.
my code is the same as here - https://github.com/ivanacostarubio/swift-in-app-purchase-example/blob/master/In%20App%20Purchase%20Example/ViewController.swift

The problem is here, the SKPaymentTransaction always fail -

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]!)    {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                //*ALWAYS FAIL*
                println("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
                // case .Restored:
                //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow [Ray In App Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started) , make sure to follow these steps.

If you already sure that you went thru the right directions :

1. Check that your IAP Product App ID is correct.
2. Check that In App Purchases is activated thru the "Capabilities" section.
3. Make sure that your app is connected to the app over Itunes Connect.

Good luck